# How to round to nearest int when casting float to int in go

Tags: go

When casting float to int the decimal is discarded. What's a clean way to cast so that it rounds to the nearest whole number instead.

`x := int(3.6)`
should equal 4 instead of 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go: Converting float64 to int with multiplier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33206059/go-converting-float64-to-int-with-multiplier)

Comment: Related issue: [math: add a Round function](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4594)

Comment: @Akavall edited title,

Comment: `int(Round(f))` to round a float to an int. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62753031/12817546. 
`float64(i)` to set an int to a float. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737936/12817546.

Comment: Has this changed? See https://go.dev/play/p/tEKYVunbNd_x.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`int(f+0.5)` will cause upwards rounding if it's >= .5

This only works well for low precision rounding. E.g.

```
var f1 = 6.499999999999999
var f2 = 6.4999999999999999
var i1 = int(f1+0.5) // equals 6
var i2 = int(f2+0.5) // equals 7
```

This can cause non-deterministic behavior. See answer below w/ math.round for a better solution.

Comment: This provides a *type conversion*; please note that the term *cast* is not used.

Comment: Also, your type conversion will not work well with negative numbers if you intended the rounding to be to the *nearest* whole integer.

Answer (score 11):

You could use `int(math.Round(f))` to round to the nearest whole number when converting a float to an int in Go. The decimal is also discarded when a float is set to a byte or a rune. Truncation doesn't happen when it's set to a string or a bool.

```
package main

import (
  . "fmt"
  . "math"
)

func main() {
  f := 3.6
  c := []interface{}{byte(f), f, int(Round(f)), rune(f), Sprintf("%.f", f), f != 0}
  checkType(c)
}
func checkType(s []interface{}) {
  for k, _ := range s {
     Printf("%T %v\n", s[k], s[k])
  }
}
```

Round returns the nearest integer, rounding half away from zero. See https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Round. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61503758/12817546.

`f := 3.6` truncates to “uint8 3”, `f` is “float64 3.6”, `int(Round(f))` rounds up to “int 4”,  `rune(f)` truncates to “int32 3”,  `Sprintf("%.f", f)` is “string 3.6” and `f != 0` outputs “bool true”.

Comment: A boolean, numeric, or string type can be set to another type. For`[]byte` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62725637/12817546, `int` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737936/12817546, `[]rune` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62739051/12817546, `string` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546 and for `bool` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62726854/12817546.