# Golang Round to Nearest 0.05

Tags: math, go, rounding

**I am looking for a function to round to the nearest 0.05 in Golang**.
The end result of using the function must always be a factor of 0.05.

---

Here are some examples of outputs for the function I am looking for:
(The function Round doesn't exist yet, I am hoping it can be included in the answer)

```
Round(0.363636) // 0.35
Round(3.232)    // 3.25
Round(0.4888)   // 0.5
```

*I have searched around for ages now and haven't found any answers.*

Comment: Related: [Go: Converting float64 to int with multiplier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33206059/go-converting-float64-to-int-with-multiplier)

Comment: If you have a rounding function that gives correct result, all you need to do is manage the result's precision by truncating it. A sort of ham-fisted approach for that would be https://play.golang.org/p/DRTTkQQI42 (not edge tested)

Comment: As the accepted answer says, rounding a binary floating-point value to some number (other than 0) of decimal places is not particularly useful. The value `0.05`, for example, cannot be represented exactly. In 64-bit IEEE floating-point, it will probably be stored as `0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125`. For most purposes, keep your floating-point values in full precision, and round them only when performing output or converting to a string.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

**Foreword:** I released this utility in [`github.com/icza/gox`](https://github.com/icza/gox), see [`mathx.Round()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/icza/gox/mathx#Round).

---

Go 1.10 has been released, and it adds a [`math.Round()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Round) function. This function rounds to the nearest integer (which is basically a *"round to nearest 1.0"* operation), and using that we can very easily construct a function that rounds to the unit of our choice:

```
func Round(x, unit float64) float64 {
    return math.Round(x/unit) * unit
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(Round(0.363636, 0.05)) // 0.35
fmt.Println(Round(3.232, 0.05))    // 3.25
fmt.Println(Round(0.4888, 0.05))   // 0.5

fmt.Println(Round(-0.363636, 0.05)) // -0.35
fmt.Println(Round(-3.232, 0.05))    // -3.25
fmt.Println(Round(-0.4888, 0.05))   // -0.5
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/z5KrxxAQesK).

The original answer follows which was created before Go 1.10 when no `math.Round()` existed, and which also details the logic behind our custom `Round()` function. It's here for educational purposes.

---

In the pre-Go1.10 era there was no `math.Round()`. But...

Rounding tasks can easily be implemented by a `float64` => `int64` converison, but care must be taken as float to int conversion is *not rounding but keeping the integer part* (see details in [Go: Converting float64 to int with multiplier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33206059/go-converting-float64-to-int-with-multiplier)).

For example:

```
var f float64
f = 12.3
fmt.Println(int64(f)) // 12
f = 12.6
fmt.Println(int64(f)) // 12
```

Result is `12` in both cases, the integer part. To get the rounding "functionality", simply add `0.5`:

```
f = 12.3
fmt.Println(int64(f + 0.5)) // 12
f = 12.6
fmt.Println(int64(f + 0.5)) // 13
```

So far so good. But we don't want to round to integers. If we'd wanted to round to 1 fraction digit, we would multiply by 10 before adding `0.5` and converting:

```
f = 12.31
fmt.Println(float64(int64(f*10+0.5)) / 10) // 12.3
f = 12.66
fmt.Println(float64(int64(f*10+0.5)) / 10) // 12.7
```

So basically you multiply by the reciprocal of the unit you want to round to. To round to `0.05` units, multiply by `1/0.05 = 20`:

```
f = 12.31
fmt.Println(float64(int64(f*20+0.5)) / 20) // 12.3
f = 12.66
fmt.Println(float64(int64(f*20+0.5)) / 20) // 12.65
```

Wrapping this into a function:

```
func Round(x, unit float64) float64 {
    return float64(int64(x/unit+0.5)) * unit
}
```

Using it:

```
fmt.Println(Round(0.363636, 0.05)) // 0.35
fmt.Println(Round(3.232, 0.05))    // 3.25
fmt.Println(Round(0.4888, 0.05))   // 0.5
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DHnn_SgdAm).

Note that rounding `3.232` with `unit=0.05` will not print exactly `3.25` but `0.35000000000000003`. This is because `float64` numbers are stored using finite precision, called the [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard. For details see [Golang converting float64 to int error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052922/golang-converting-float64-to-int-error).

Also note that `unit` may be "any" number. If it's `1`, then `Round()` basically rounds to nearest integer number. If it's `10`, it rounds to tens, if it's `0.01`, it rounds to 2 fraction digits.

Also note that when you call `Round()` with a negative number, you might get surprising result:

```
fmt.Println(Round(-0.363636, 0.05)) // -0.3
fmt.Println(Round(-3.232, 0.05))    // -3.2
fmt.Println(Round(-0.4888, 0.05))   // -0.45
```

This is because –as said earlier– conversion is keeping the integer part, and for example integer part of `-1.6` is `-1` (which is greater than `-1.6`; while integer part of `1.6` is `1` which is less than `1.6`).

If you want `-0.363636` to become `-0.35` instead of `-0.30`, then in case of negative numbers add `-0.5` instead of `0.5` inside the `Round()` function. See our improved `Round2()` function:

```
func Round2(x, unit float64) float64 {
    if x > 0 {
        return float64(int64(x/unit+0.5)) * unit
    }
    return float64(int64(x/unit-0.5)) * unit
}
```

And using it:

```
fmt.Println(Round2(-0.363636, 0.05)) // -0.35
fmt.Println(Round2(-3.232, 0.05))    // -3.25
fmt.Println(Round2(-0.4888, 0.05))   // -0.5
```

---

**EDIT:**

To address your comment: because you don't "like" the non-exact `0.35000000000000003`, you proposed to format it and re-parse it like:

```
formatted, err := strconv.ParseFloat(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", rounded), 64)
```

And this "seemingly" results in the exact result as printing it gives `0.35` exactly.

But this is just an "illusion". Since `0.35` cannot be represented with finite bits using IEEE-754 standard, doesn't matter what you do with the number, if you store it in a value of type `float64`, it won't be exactly `0.35` (but an IEEE-754 number being very close to it). What you see is `fmt.Println()` printing it as `0.35` because `fmt.Println()` already does some rounding.

But if you attempt to print it with higher precision:

```
fmt.Printf("%.30f\n", Round(0.363636, 0.05))
fmt.Printf("%.30f\n", Round(3.232, 0.05))
fmt.Printf("%.30f\n", Round(0.4888, 0.05))
```

Output: it's not nicer (might be even uglier): try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PnHrIw1ysw):

```
0.349999999999999977795539507497
3.250000000000000000000000000000
0.500000000000000000000000000000
```

Note that on the other hand `3.25` and `0.5` are exact because they can be represented with finite bits exactly, because representing in binary:

```
3.25 = 3 + 0.25 = 11.01binary
0.5 = 0.1binary
```

What's the lesson? It's not worth formatting and re-parsing the result, as it won't be exact either (just a different `float64` value which –according to default `fmt.Println()` formatting rules– might be nicer in printing). If you want nice printed format, just format with precision, like:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%.3f\n", Round(0.363636, 0.05))
    fmt.Printf("%.3f\n", Round(3.232, 0.05))
    fmt.Printf("%.3f\n", Round(0.4888, 0.05))
}

func Round(x, unit float64) float64 {
    return float64(int64(x/unit+0.5)) * unit
}
```

And it will be exact (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/11GbPjkDKq)):

```
0.350
3.250
0.500
```

Or just multiply them by `100` and work with integer numbers, so that no representation or rounding error may occur.

Comment: Nothing more than pure genius. Thank you icza.

Comment: @Acidic Please see edit regarding applying it on negative numbers.

Comment: Yep, I see thank you. I've edited your function to solve the problem of 0.363636 = 0.35000000000000003 which is available at https://play.golang.org/p/jxILFBYBEF for anyone interested.

Comment: @Acidic Formatting and re-parsing gives you nothing more that "illusion". See edited answer. Unnecessary to do that.

Comment: @icza What about check for overflow?

Comment: @PickBoy That is not covered by this answer as the question was about rounding (errors).