# Conversion of time.Duration type microseconds value to milliseconds

Tags: go, time

I am using go-ping ( https://github.com/sparrc/go-ping )library of golang for unprivileged ICMP ping.

```
timeout := time.Second*1000
interval := time.Second
count := 5
host := p.ipAddr
pinger, cmdErr := ping.NewPinger(host)

pinger.Count = count
pinger.Interval = interval
pinger.Timeout = timeout
pinger.SetPrivileged(false)
pinger.Run()
stats := pinger.Statistics()

latency = stats.AvgRtt  // stats.AvgRtt is time.Duration type
jitter = stats.StdDevRtt// stats.StdDevRtt is time.Duration type
```

From running this, I am getting latency in milliseconds and jitter in microseconds. I want same unit for both let's say millisecond so when I am doing `jitter = stats.StdDevRtt/1000` or `jitter = jitter/1000` (to convert microseconds to milliseconds), what I am getting is jitter in nanoseconds :(. Is there any way to get same unit milliseconds for both latency and jitter.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

#### Number to `time.Duration`

[`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) is a type having `int64` as its [underlying type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types), which stores the duration in nanoseconds.

If you know the value but you want other than nanoseconds, simply multiply the unit you want, e.g.:

```
d := 100 * time.Microsecond
fmt.Println(d) // Output: 100µs
```

The above works because `100` is an untyped [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants), and it can be converted automatically to `time.Duration` which has `int64` underlying type.

Note that if you have the value as a typed value, you have to use explicit [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
value := 100 // value is of type int

d2 := time.Duration(value) * time.Millisecond
fmt.Println(d2) // Output: 100ms
```

#### `time.Duration` to number

So `time.Duration` is always the nanoseconds. If you need it in milliseconds for example, all you need to do is divide the `time.Duration` value with the number of nanoseconds in a millisecond:

```
ms := int64(d2 / time.Millisecond)
fmt.Println("ms:", ms) // Output: ms: 100
```

Other examples:

```
fmt.Println("ns:", int64(d2/time.Nanosecond))  // ns: 100000000
fmt.Println("µs:", int64(d2/time.Microsecond)) // µs: 100000
fmt.Println("ms:", int64(d2/time.Millisecond)) // ms: 100
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xLmj_Qzb81).

If your jitter (duration) is less than the unit you wish to convert it to, you need to use floating point division, else an integer division will be performed which cuts off the fraction part. For details see: [Golang Round to Nearest 0.05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544571/golang-round-to-nearest-0-05/39544897#39544897).

Convert both the jitter and unit to `float64` before dividing:

```
d := 61 * time.Microsecond
fmt.Println(d) // Output: 61µs

ms := float64(d) / float64(time.Millisecond)
fmt.Println("ms:", ms) // Output: ms: 0.061
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mdB_JMw_zN)):

```
61µs
ms: 0.061
```

Comment: I want to convert jitter to milliseconds which I am getting in microseconds.
jitter is time.Duration type. And this is not working for it. I tried doing
jitter = (stats.StdDevRtt/time.Nanosecond).

Comment: @supriya It's the second half of my answer: to get it in milliseconds: `ms := int64(d2 / time.Millisecond)`

Comment: when I am doing ms := int64(d2 / time.Millisecond), it is giving jitter =0 which is right as jitter I am getting is 61 microseconds which will be 0.061 milliseconds and when rounded off with int, it will give 0 as jitter value, but this is not what I want... I want jitter value in decimal places i.e. 0.061.... Is there any way to do so?

Comment: it worked.One more doubt I have. What it is printing now is "0.061". Can I get it like "0.061 ms" ?

Comment: @supriya You can print it however you like: `fmt.Printf("%.3f ms", ms)`.

Answer (score 17):

As of Go 1.13, you can use new Duration methods `Microseconds` and `Milliseconds` which return the duration as an integer count of their respectively named units.

https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#time

Comment: Remark : these methods truncate do not round. For example for 0.999μs we can see that  `time.Duration(999).Microseconds()` returns `0`.

Answer (score 5):

The type of `latency` and `jitter` variables is `time.Duration` which per [definition](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) its base type is int64 and is expressed in nanoseconds.

When you use print functions the [`String`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/6365efb7dcfd6ab90ffe5541ca26bd8d875167a3/src/time/time.go#L619)‍‍‍‍ ‍method of type `time.Duration` is invoked and it uses `h`, `s`, `m`, `µ`, `n` notations when printing the duration, here is the documentation for `String` method:

```
// String returns a string representing the duration in the form "72h3m0.5s".
// Leading zero units are omitted. As a special case, durations less than one
// second format use a smaller unit (milli-, micro-, or nanoseconds) to ensure
// that the leading digit is non-zero. The zero duration formats as 0s.
```

There are some pre-defined [constants](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) in the `time` package which you can use to convert the duration variable to your preferred unit of time, e.g.:

```
latencyInMicroSeconds := int64(jitter / time.Microsecond)
```

Pay attention that we converted it to an `int` type because if you won't it would be still in `time.Duration` type and the value of that type is considered to be in nanosecond unit but now it's microsecond which causes a further problem in calculations if you're going to use `time` package functions.

Comment: I tried doing jitterInMilliSeconds := (jitter / time.Microsecond) so what I am getting is jitter in nanoseconds now.... as you have written in your answer that while printing time.Duration type value, string method is called and it ensures that while printing , leading digit is non-zero. As jitter value I am getting is 64.6 microsecond so in miliseconds it will be 0.064 milliseconds which is less than zero. So is it the reason that I am getting it on nanoceconds when divided by time.Microsecond... Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @supriya sorry, `jitterInMilliSeconds` variable should be `latencyInMicroSeconds` (already fixed), maybe this sample helps to figure it out: https://gist.github.com/sepehrmm/0c46f3b6cc417c9db21c15f767197c4a