# Operation on seconds in function

Tags: go, time

I'm currently working on a project and I face a problem in a function that returns the `startTime` of a call. Here is my code:

```
func (bt *Hc34) getStartDate(endTime time.Time, duration int) time.Time {
     startTime := endTime
     startTime.Second = endTime.Second - duration

     return startTime
}
```

And I get this error:

```
beater/hc34.go:268: invalid operation: endTime.Second - duration (mismatched types func() int and int)
beater/hc34.go:268: cannot assign to startTime.Second
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) has no exported field `Second`, so `startTime.Second` is invalid.

There is a [`Time.Add()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Add) method which you may use to add a [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) value to a `time.Time` value. And to subtract a duration from it, simply multiply the value you add with `-1`.

```
func (bt *Hc34) getStartDate(endTime time.Time, duration int) time.Time {
    return endTime.Add(time.Duration(-duration) * time.Second)
}
```

Example with a `getStartDate()` function (not method):

```
now := time.Now()
fmt.Println(now)
fmt.Println(getStartDate(now, 60))
```

Output on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4sBbetvX92):

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
2009-11-10 22:59:00 +0000 UTC
```

I also recommend to read this answer about using `time.Duration` values constructed from integers: [Conversion of time.Duration type microseconds value to milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503758/conversion-of-time-duration-type-microseconds-value-to-milliseconds-in-golang/41503910#41503910)