# Time in seconds with time.Since

Tags: go, time

I have a following function which calculated time since `startTime`, uptime:  `time.Since(startTime).String()`.

This returns time as follows:

```
"uptime": "3m54.26744075s"
```

How do I convert time to be in seconds, as follows:

```
"uptime": "123456789"
```

Comment: Devide by 1 time.Second.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/time/

Answer (score 13):

[`time.Since()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Since) returns you a value of type [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) which has a [`Duration.Seconds()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration.Seconds) method, just use that:

```
secs := time.Since(startTime).Seconds()
```

This will be of type `float64`. If you don't need the fraction part, just convert it to `int`, e.g. `int(secs)`. Alternatively you may divide the `time.Duration` value with `time.Second` (which is the number of nanoseconds in a second), and you'll get to an integer seconds value right away:

```
secs := int(time.Since(startTime) / time.Second)
```

(Note that the `int` conversion in this last example is not to drop the fraction part because this is already an integer division, but it's rather to have the result as a value of type `int` instead of `time.Duration`.)

Also see related question: [Conversion of time.Duration type microseconds value to milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503758/conversion-of-time-duration-type-microseconds-value-to-milliseconds/41503910#41503910)