# When does `int * time.Second` work and when does it not in golang?

Tags: go

Why does `time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)` work fine, but:

```
x := 180
time.Sleep(15 / x * 60 * time.Second)
```

does not? I get a type mismatch error (types `int64` and `time.Duration`). Given the error, I understand more of why the latter fails than why the former succeeds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion of time.Duration type microseconds value to milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503758/conversion-of-time-duration-type-microseconds-value-to-milliseconds/41503910#41503910).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Go, a [numeric literal (e.g. `60`) is an *untyped constant*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants). That means it will be silently coerced to whatever type is appropriate for the operation where it's being used. So when you say:

```
var x := 5 * time.Second
```

Then the type is inferred from `time.Second` to be a `time.Duration`, and thus the literal `5` is also treated as a `time.Duration`. If there's nothing to infer a type from, it will assume a type ("bool, rune, int, float64, complex128 or string") and use that. So:

```
x := 180
```

Yields `x` with a type of `int`.

However, when you do some operation involving something with a type - like, say a variable `x` that is an `int` - then you have two types and one must be converted for the operation to be legal.

So, to the original question "When does `int * time.Second` work and when does it not in golang?", `int * time.Second` actually *never* works in Go. But `5 * time.Second` isn't the same as `int * time.Second`.

This is touched on in [the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/basics/16):

> An untyped constant takes the type needed by its context.

Comment: So exactly which type does the variable need to be ?

Comment: @stevea the same type as the other operand - in this case, `time.Duration`, which is the type of `time.Second`.