# How can I truncate float64 number to a particular precision?

Tags: go, floating-point, truncate

I want to truncate `1.234567` into a 3-fraction digit floating point number, but the result is not what I want.

E.g: `1.234567` => `1.234`

```
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    f := 1.234567
    fmt.Println(strconv.FormatFloat(f, 'f', 3, 64)) //1.235
    fmt.Printf("%.3f", f) //1.235
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this in Go?

Comment: What you want is to round (or truncate) to 3 fraction digits, not bits. For general rounding, see possible duplicate: [Golang Round to Nearest 0.05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544571/golang-round-to-nearest-0-05/39544897#39544897)

Comment: I don't want round, just truncate  to 3 fraction digits.
 1.234567 => 1.234 not 1.235

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The naive way (not always correct)

For truncation, we could take advantage of [`math.Trunc()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Trunc) which throws away the fraction digits. This is not exactly what we want, we want to keep some fraction digits. So in order to achieve what we want, we may first multiply the input by a power of 10 to shift the wanted fraction digits to the "integer" part, and after truncation (calling `math.Trunc()` which will throw away the remaining fraction digits), we can divide by the same power of 10 we multiplied in the beginning:

```
f2 := math.Trunc(f*1000) / 1000
```

Wrapping this into a function:

```
func truncateNaive(f float64, unit float64) float64 {
    return math.Trunc(f/unit) * unit
}
```

Testing it:

```
f := 1.234567
f2 := truncateNaive(f, 0.001)
fmt.Printf("%.10f\n", f2)
```

Output:

```
1.2340000000
```

So far so good, but note that we perform arithmetic operations inside `truncateNaive()` which may result in unwanted roundings, which could alter the output of the function.

For example, if the input is `0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875` (it's representable by a `float64` value exactly, see [proof](https://play.golang.org/p/I-H2RQJ6Lj4)), the output should be `0.2999000000`, but it will be something else:

```
f = 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
f2 = truncateNaive(f, 0.001)
fmt.Printf("%.10f\n", f2)
```

Output:

```
0.3000000000
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eWXfIJG46MF).

This wrong output is probably not acceptable in most cases (except if you look at it from a way that the input is *very* close to `0.3`–difference is less than 10<sup>-16</sup>–to which the output is `0.3`...).

### Using `big.Float`

To properly truncate all valid `float64` values, the intermediate operations must be precise. To achieve that, using a single `float64` is insufficient. There are ways to split the input into 2 `float64` values and perform operations on them (so precision is not lost) which would be more efficient, or we could use a more convenient way, [`big.Float`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float) which can be of arbitrary precision.

Here's the "transcript" of the above `truncateNaive()` function using `big.Float`:

```
func truncate(f float64, unit float64) float64 {
    bf := big.NewFloat(0).SetPrec(1000).SetFloat64(f)
    bu := big.NewFloat(0).SetPrec(1000).SetFloat64(unit)

    bf.Quo(bf, bu)

    // Truncate:
    i := big.NewInt(0)
    bf.Int(i)
    bf.SetInt(i)

    f, _ = bf.Mul(bf, bu).Float64()
    return f
}
```

Testing it:

```
f := 1.234567
f2 := truncate(f, 0.001)
fmt.Printf("%.10f\n", f2)

f = 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
f2 = truncate(f, 0.001)
fmt.Printf("%.10f\n", f2)
```

Output is now valid (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/65bc1Opm8sf)):

```
1.2340000000
0.2990000000
```

Comment: `f = 1.234
f2 := truncate(f, 0.001)
fmt.Printf("%.10f\n", f2) //1.2330000000
`

Comment: @ikool That's because `1.234` cannot be represented exactly with `float64`. When you assign `1.234` to a `float64`, that's gonna be `1.233999999999999985789145284798`, see it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/npqET4ys3b3). So essentially you truncate `1.233999999999999985789145284798`, for which the correct output is `1.233`.

Comment: `truncate(0.123456789, 0.000000001)` [gives](https://go.dev/play/p/Rmhj2wJ2J7w) `0.12345678800000001`

Comment: @eprst And that's because the value you pass is **not** `0.123456789` because it can't be represented using `float64`, the value you pass is `0.1234567889999999973361`, and applying the truncation to _this_ is `0.123456788` (which again can't be represented using `float64`, the closest is `0.12345678800000001`). See here: https://go.dev/play/p/DMt7Hd8R2Ax

Comment: @icza Is there a reason why we shouldn't use `big.MaxPrec` as precision ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to truncate decimals manually, either on string level or with `math.Floor`  like https://play.golang.org/p/UP2gFx2iFru.

Comment: This gives wrong result if the input is `0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875`, see my answer.

Comment: That number doesn't fit float64. ;-) But you're right, there is a minor chance of roundig errors when you hit a lot of 9s.

Comment: That number is representable by a `float64` exactly, see https://play.golang.org/p/I-H2RQJ6Lj4

Comment: The `float64` is limited to 15 decimals. Your interesting example renders as this exact sequence of decimals due to the algorithms below. Try changing a digit @icza as in: https://play.golang.org/p/pXHwWCyTH-o. ;-)

Comment: The `float64` type is a binary representation ([IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)), it has finite bits for representing the number, but a finite binary number may have more decimal digits. Just like the finite `0.3` decimal number has an infinite binary representation. (The linked wikipedia page has such example, check it.)