# How can I convert float(-1.0) to int -1 correctly?

Tags: go

my code:

```golang
step := 10.0
precision := int(math.Log10(1/step))
fmt.PrintLn(precision)
```

I want precision == -1 but got 0...

Answer (score 2):

Float to integer conversion truncates, so if your float number is e.g. `0.99`, converting it to integer will be `0` and not `1`.

If you want to round to an integer, you may simply use [`math.Round()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Round) (which returns `float64` so you still need to manually convert to `int`, but the result will be what you expect):

```
step := 10.0
precision := int(math.Log10(1 / step))
fmt.Println(precision)

precision = int(math.Round(math.Log10(1 / step)))
fmt.Println(precision)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FB8UBVGBGFa)):

```
0
-1
```

If you want to round to a specific fraction (and not to integer), see [Golang Round to Nearest 0.05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544571/golang-round-to-nearest-0-05/39544897#39544897).

Comment: So cute you are, I just fix this problem lastnignt with same method, but I spend a long time to figure out the thought.