# Different results while rounding to nearest thousand using math.Pow

Tags: go, rounding

I was trying to round a number to the nearest thousand but I usually get a different result when I use math.Pow. Examples:

```
fmt.Println(math.Pow(10., 3.))
x := math.Pow(10, 3)
y := (((3251 - 1000) / x) * x)
fmt.Println(y)

Output: 1000
Output: 2251
```

[GoPlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/QLBbABUBkef)

When I use 1000 instead math.Pow(10., 3.) I get what I want:

```
y := (((3251 - 1000) / 1000) * 1000)
fmt.Println(y)

Output: 2000
```

[Go PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/4LjA2cakW04)

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate some help.

Comment: The first is floating point arithmetic. This `(((3251 - 1000) / 1000) * 1000)` is integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `y := ((3251 - 1000) / 1000) * 1000` is a [constant expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions), i.e. has only constant untyped literal operands, and it's evaluated at compile time. In particular:

> If the untyped operands of a binary operation (other than a shift) are of different kinds, the result is of the operand's kind that appears later in this list

The last operands `1000` (of both the division and multiplication) are an **untyped** `int`, therefore the result of the division is also an `int`, and truncated to integer precision as you were expecting:

```
    // (3251 - 1000) -> int 2251
    // (3251 - 1000) / 1000 -> int 2
    // ((3251 - 1000) / 1000) * 1000 -> int 2000

    y := ((3251 - 1000) / 1000) * 1000
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(y)) // int
```

With `math.Pow` instead the expression is not constant anymore (it's the result of a function call), and now you have a **typed** `float64` variable resulting from the return type of `Pow`:

```
    // (3251 - 1000) -> 2251 int
    // (3251 - 1000) / x -> 2.251 float64
    // ((3251 - 1000) / x) * x -> 2251 float64

    y := (((3251 - 1000) / x) * x)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(y)) // float64
```

So in the latter case, the decimal that results from the division is preserved and you get it back after you multiply it again.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/v_mX3mnM6tT

---

To round to the nearest thousand you can use the trick suggested by [@icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39544897/4108803):

```
func Round(x, unit float64) float64 {
    return math.Round(x/unit) * unit
}

func main() {
    x := Round(3251-1000, 1000.)
    fmt.Println(x) // 2000
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent explanation :). So if I need to round to the nearest thousand I would need to do the covnersion of math.Pow(x, y) to int, right? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @JMaia the very short answer is that you could do it that way, but please check [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39544897/4108803) by [icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza) which contains a detailed explanation and guideline about rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(math.Pow(10, 3))
    x := math.Pow(10, 3)
    y := (((3251 - 1000) / x) * x)
    fmt.Println(y)
    fmt.Println(Round(y, 1000))
}
func Round(x, unit float64) float64 {
    return math.Round(x/unit) * unit
}
```

Output:

```
1000
2251
2000
```