# How to fix calculation error in go math operations with floats?

Tags: go

I need to normalise a value (degrees) to have it in some range. I need to get a reminder of division by 360.

```golang
func testFunc(t *testing.T) {

    v := -1050.6
    n := int(v / 360)
    f := v - float64(n)*360

    fmt.Printf("f: %v\n", f)
}
```

The value I expect is `-330.6` the value I get is `-330.5999999999999`. This happens when I do `v - float64(n)*360`. Is there any way to get rid of this error?

Comment: That is not an error, that is how float64 stores the precision for the value stored.

Comment: Yup, I know. But is there any way to correctly round it ?

Comment: You can round to arbitrary precision: [Golang Round to Nearest 0.05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544571/golang-round-to-nearest-0-05/39544897#39544897)

Comment: Is it only a display problem? Then try this:`fmt.Printf("%.2f\n", v)`

Comment: You need to read Goldberg's paper from A[i]CM Computing Surveys[/i], Vol 23, No 1, March 1991, ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About
Floating-Point Arithmetic"](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf), and visit https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: thanks! I those articles really give a comprehensive answer. My question raised from a goal to keep representativeness. I'm not converting those number but sending forward where it would be better to keep it "nice"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (2 digits after comma):

```
fmt.Println(math.Round(f * 100) / 100)
```